# How to StringReplace a '\' with AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Trying do do a simple

```
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, \, /, All
```

That code works w/ other characters, but gives an error with '\' and/or '/'
also tried ASCII codes but those do not work either since % is a variable in AHK.

How to StringReplace a '\' with AutoHotkey?

Comment: `StringReplace` is deprecated now, so use `clipboard := strReplace(clipboard, "\", "/")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get no error using that line. I used the following snippet to test:

```
CapsLock & p::
clipboard = are\there\backslashes?
MsgBox, %clipboard%
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, \, /, All
MsgBox, %clipboard%
return
```

I'm using AutoHotKey 1.0.46.1 (which is probably old by now...) on a Windows XP laptop.

What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for checking; Using the newer version.

Comment: Just tried this again and it works now; Not sure what I did wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `\` as the escape character

```
#EscapeChar \
```

then the code should be

```
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, \\, /, All
```